# If Not Null Replace with regex, if is Null, do nothing

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace, null

I only want the regex to be applied if $_.Skuname is not Null and not blank, that way it does not convert the Nulls to strings.  Is this possible, if so, how?

```
(Get-SQLInstance -Computername $Computer | foreach { $_.Skuname }) -replace '(\w+) .+', '$1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the if/then statement within your foreach, something like this:

`(Get-SQLInstance -Computername $Computer | foreach { if ($_.Skuname) { $_.Skuname -replace '(\w+) .+', '$1'} }`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It was my pleasure!